# More interruptions than cpu context switches

Tags: debian, context-switch

I have a machine running Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.8 (lenny) 8 cores and 12Gb of RAM.
We have one core permanently around 40% ~ 60% wait time and trying to spot what is happening I realized that we have more interruptions than cpu context switches. I found that the normal ratio between context switch and interruptions is around 10x more context switching than interruptions but on my server the values are completely different.

```
backend1:~# vmstat -s
  12330788 K total memory
  12221676 K used memory
   3668624 K active memory
   6121724 K inactive memory
    109112 K free memory
   3929400 K buffer memory
   4095536 K swap cache
   4194296 K total swap
      7988 K used swap
   4186308 K free swap
  44547459 non-nice user cpu ticks
    702408 nice user cpu ticks
  13346333 system cpu ticks
1607583668 idle cpu ticks
 374043393 IO-wait cpu ticks
   4144149 IRQ cpu ticks
   3994255 softirq cpu ticks
         0 stolen cpu ticks
4445557114 pages paged in
2910596714 pages paged out
    128642 pages swapped in
    267400 pages swapped out
3519307319 interrupts
2464686911 CPU context switches
1306744317 boot time
  11555115 forks
```

Any ideas if that is an issue? And in that case, how can I spot the cause and fix it?

**Update**

Following the instructions of the comments and focusing on the core stuck in wait I checked the processes attached to that core and below you can find the list:

```
   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  P COMMAND
    24 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:03.42 7 migration/7                                                                                                                              
    25 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:04.78 7 ksoftirqd/7                                                                                                                              
    26 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 watchdog/7                                                                                                                               
    34 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   1:18.90 7 events/7                                                                                                                                 
    83 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   1:10.68 7 kblockd/7                                                                                                                                
   291 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 aio/7                                                                                                                                    
   569 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 ata/7                                                                                                                                    
  1545 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 ksnapd                                                                                                                                   
  1644 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:36.73 7 kjournald                                                                                                                                
  1725 root      16  -4 16940 1152  488 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 udevd                                                                                                                                    
  2342 root      20   0  8828 1140  956 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 sh                                                                                                                                       
  2375 root      20   0  8848 1220 1016 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 locate                                                                                                                                   
  2421 root      30  10  8896 1268 1016 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 updatedb.findut                                                                                                                          
  2430 root      30  10 58272  49m  616 S    0  0.4   0:17.44 7 sort                                                                                                                                     
  2431 root      30  10  3792  448  360 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 frcode                                                                                                                                   
  2682 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   3:25.98 7 kjournald                                                                                                                                
  2683 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.64 7 kjournald                                                                                                                                
  2687 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   1:31.30 7 kjournald                                                                                                                                
  3261 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   2:30.56 7 kondemand/7                                                                                                                              
  3364 root      20   0  3796  596  476 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 acpid                                                                                                                                    
  3575 root      20   0  8828 1140  956 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 sh                                                                                                                                       
  3597 root      20   0  8848 1216 1016 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 locate                                                                                                                                   
  3603 root      30  10  8896 1268 1016 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 updatedb.findut                                                                                                                          
  3612 root      30  10 58272  49m  616 S    0  0.4   0:27.04 7 sort                                                                                                                                     
  3655 root      20   0 11056 2852  516 S    0  0.0   5:36.46 7 redis-server                                                                                                                             
  3706 root      20   0 19832 1056  816 S    0  0.0   0:01.64 7 cron                                                                                                                                     
  3746 root      20   0  3796  580  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 getty                                                                                                                                    
  3748 root      20   0  3796  580  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 getty                                                                                                                                    
  7674 root      20   0 28376 1000  736 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 cron                                                                                                                                     
  7675 root      20   0  8828 1140  956 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 sh                                                                                                                                       
  7708 root      30  10 58272  49m  616 S    0  0.4   0:03.36 7 sort                                                                                                                                     
 22049 root      20   0  8828 1136  956 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 sh                                                                                                                                       
 22095 root      20   0  8848 1220 1016 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 locate                                                                                                                                   
 22099 root      30  10  8896 1264 1016 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 updatedb.findut                                                                                                                          
 22108 root      30  10 58272  49m  616 S    0  0.4   0:44.55 7 sort                                                                                                                                     
 22109 root      30  10  3792  452  360 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 frcode                                                                                                                                   
 26927 root      20   0  8828 1140  956 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 sh                                                                                                                                       
 26947 root      20   0  8848 1216 1016 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 locate                                                                                                                                   
 26951 root      30  10  8896 1268 1016 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 updatedb.findut                                                                                                                          
 26960 root      30  10 58272  49m  616 S    0  0.4   0:10.24 7 sort                                                                                                                                     
 26961 root      30  10  3792  452  360 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 frcode                                                                                                                                   
 27952 root      20   0 65948 3028 2400 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 sshd                                                                                                                                     
 30731 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.34 7 pdflush                                                                                                                                  
 31204 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.24 7 pdflush
 21857 deploy    20   0 1227m 2240  868 S    0  0.0   2:44.22 7 nginx                                                                                                                                    
 21858 deploy    20   0 1228m 2784  868 S    0  0.0   2:42.45 7 nginx                                                                                                                                    
 21862 deploy    20   0 1228m 2732  868 S    0  0.0   2:43.90 7 nginx                                                                                                                                    
 21869 deploy    20   0 1228m 2840  868 S    0  0.0   2:44.14 7 nginx                                                                                                                                    
 27994 deploy    20   0 19372 2216 1380 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 7 bash                                                                                                                                     
 28493 deploy    20   0  331m  32m  16m S    4  0.3   0:00.40 7 apache2                                                                                                                                  
 21856 deploy    20   0 1228m 2844  868 S    0  0.0   2:43.64 7 nginx
  3622 nobody    30  10 21156  10m  916 D    0  0.1   4:42.31 7 find                                                                                                                                     
  7716 nobody    30  10 12268 1280  888 D    0  0.0   0:43.50 7 find                                                                                                                                     
 22116 nobody    30  10 12612 1696  916 D    0  0.0   6:32.26 7 find                                                                                                                                     
 26968 nobody    30  10 12268 1284  888 D    0  0.0   1:56.92 7 find
```

**Update**

As suggested I take a look at /proc/interrupts and below the info there:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7
  0:         35          0          0 1469085485          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          0          0          0          8          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  8:          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          0          0          0        105          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  580212114   IO-APIC-fasteoi   3w-9xxx, uhci_hcd:usb1
 18:          0          0        142          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb6, ehci_hcd:usb7
 19:          9          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb3, uhci_hcd:usb5
 21:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb2
 23:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4, ehci_hcd:usb8
1273:         0          0 1600400502          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
1274:         0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ahci
NMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:  214252181   69439018  317298553   21943690   72562482   56448835  137923978  407514738   Local timer interrupts
RES:   27516446   16935944   26430972   44957009   24935543   19881887   57746906   24298747   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:      10655      10705      10685      10567      10689      10669      10667        396   function call interrupts
TLB:     529548     462587     801138     596193     922202     747313    2027966     946594   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
ERR:          0
```

All the values seems more or less the same for all the cores but this one `IO-APIC-fasteoi   3w-9xxx, uhci_hcd:usb1` only affects to the core 7 (the same with the wait time of 40% ~ 60%) could be something attached to the usb port causing the issue?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: How is an ubuntu machine running debian?

Comment: 3molo you are right, I made a mistake, we have also a bunch of servers on ubuntu and I just get confused.

Comment: On its own I wouldn't the figures are that unusual - if the issue is that one specific core is stuck in wait then I'd be looking to see if there were any processes pinned to that cpu

Comment: @symcbean: Following your recommendation I checked the processes attached with that core with "top" and you can find the list above.

Comment: Is there any way to narrow down that list to find the process causing the wait? I suppose will be nginx or apache :S

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of a 'normal ratio of context switches to interrupts'. As other people have said, this isn't necessarily a problem. However if you have an interrupt that's occurring too frequently, that could cause the performance issues. It depends what interrupts as some are meant to occur very frequently, but for things like disk controllers or network adaptors, where the interrupt handlers are slower, a high interrupt rate can cause serious performance issues.

It's important to figure out which interrupts are occurring, and if they can be handled in some other way, such as by using polling for the device causing the problem, using a better driver, or replacing the device with a better one. I believe in linux, /proc/interrupts will lead you down the path to solving your problem.

Comment: could be a usb device... could also be your disk controller 3w-9xxx. You can investigate further in /proc/irq/16

Answer (score 2):

What does the upper part of `top` say? Is it software or hardware interrupts?

To get more information on interrupts, check out `/proc/interrupts` - this may give you an idea of your core consumption and interrupts.

You can see which interrupts are being most aggressive by running `watch -d -n 1 cat /proc/interrupts` .

You may want to look into checking your process affinity, or install something like irqbalance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is normal behaviour, are you noticing any specific performance problems?

I just checked a Ubuntu box here and got the following,

```
1406721073 interrupts

942882359 CPU context switches
```

Cheers,
Bob

Comment: Hi Bob, the only strange thing I'm seeing is a core permanently in wait status, that's it but searching I came across this thing and I don't know if it's an issue or not. BTW thanks for checking on your box ;)

Comment: Maybe whatever your box is used for does not spread efficiently over the cores.  Try specifically pushing processes onto cores.  

Taskset should be available for this.

Oh & no probs ;)